# Restrict page to members only does not work for page ID, slug or page title

Tags: pages, code, content-restriction

I was wondering why (and how to) restricting pages by the following criteria does not work. I wanted to restrict the contact page due to spam.
The code is being added and activated on front-end using the Code Snippets plugin:

```
function contactusnot()
{
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && (is_page( 220 ) || is_page( 'Contact us' ) || is_page( 'contact-us' ))) 
    {
        header("Location: https://google.com/");
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'contactusnot');
```

I've tried removing the function, hoping it will force the filter to work before anything else and also using only the ID/slug/title one by one. Now working for my Woocommerce site.

Comment: It's possible that Code Snippets loads the code on or after the `init` hook, which means your code wouldn't execute. Try moving the code outside of the hook callback, and see what happens.

Comment: nothing. no redirect with or without function

Answer (score 0):

The `init` hook is called too early for your needs. And you should use `wp_redirect()`. Try this:

```
function contactusnot() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && (is_page( 220 ) || is_page( 'Contact us' ) || is_page( 'contact-us' )))  {
       wp_redirect( 'https://google.com/' ); 
       exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'contactusnot' );
```

Comment: same result, not redirecting visitors